# Scraping Website using python to search for a specific thing

Tags: python, lxml

Language: Python
Website: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/ae2-extras/files/3120250
Goal: get the project id and store it as a variable

Snippet from website

```
<div class="w-full flex justify-between">
    <span>Project ID</span>
    <span>421104</span>
</div>
```

I want to store the project id 421104 into a variable, I've tried using lxml to get all the divs with the classes 'w-full flex justify-between' but the result is empty

My code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get(url)
doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
divs = doc.xpath("//div[@class='w-full flex justify-between']")
print(divs)
```

Output: []

What am I doing wrong? I have requests, and lxml installed in my environment
Then after I get the list off divs, how would i be able to scrape the 421104 from that first div and store it into a local variable
EDIT 2: I've solved it. Issue was the initial request was getting blocked by cloudfare, I posted my solution as an answer

Comment: Does the captcha appear via normal browser?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
page = scraper.get(url).text

doc = html.fromstring(page)
divs = doc.xpath("//div[@class='w-full flex justify-between']")
el = divs[0].text_content()
projectID = el.split()[-1]
print(projectID)
```

Answer (score 0):

My be you got a response as `<Response [403]>` when you  `print(page)` .Its mean `The HTTP 403 is a HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden`